# i build a web app in google app script where i use <img> tag in html for importing and i embed a image link from drive. and it is not visible

Tags: javascript, html, google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I embed the image form google drive. using this

```
<img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1EyMR1nYrJcpXEBpaF8tBEPj9K_8L5piS" width="100px">
```

please check the url. image is shared with anyone.

and this error is showing in web

```
Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked a cross-origin response.
1 request
 uc?id=1EyMR1nYrJcpXEBpaF8tBEPj9K_8L5piS
```

and

```
Request URL:
https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1EyMR1nYrJcpXEBpaF8tBEPj9K_8L5piS
Request Method:
GET
Status Code:
403 Forbidden
Referrer Policy:
strict-origin-when-cross-origin
```

i do not use any other way to host this image.
please help me

Please solve this bug and If you have another way than please share it with me

Comment: If you wish to display images that are stored on your drive I first convert the images to media URI with a function like this: `function convImageUrl(url) {
  var url = url || "http://jimesteban.com/images/mimincoopers.png";
  let b64Url=null;
  if (~url.indexOf('base64')) {
    b64Url = url;
  } else {
    var blob = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getBlob();
    b64Url = 'data:' + blob.getContentType() + ';base64,' + Utilities.base64Encode(blob.getBytes());
  }
  return b64Url;
}`

Comment: I usually start from the image url and then convert to media uri.  It's a string that can become the img.src where all of the data for the image is stored within the src string,